# Adding &js_fast_load=0&css_fast_load=0&strip=0 to URL triggers mojibake

Tags: liferay-6, mojibake

I have a Liferay 6.2 page that shows fine.

For debug purposes, I added `&js_fast_load=0&css_fast_load=0&strip=0` o the URL (production server that I can not modify).

Problem: By doing so, the page's encoding gets mixed up (mojibake)

What could be triggering the problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the root cause of the problem.

But as it is for debug (these URL parameters are only used for debugging), an easy way to "solve" it is to manually switch the page encoding to UTF-8.

Any better solution is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your own answer that switching to UTF-8 fixes the issue. I'd add to it that this issue points to a general problem with encoding on some level. I always recommend to always strictly and everywhere standardize on the same encoding: From Database/Filesystem/appserver to the HTTP/HTML layer. Mixing up encoding is a recipe for disaster, mainly because it will only be detected in edge cases unless you happen to work in non-latin character sets routinely.

My favorite way to test with non-latin character sets that make sense to you when you only speak languages that use latin alphabet is to utilize http://fliptitle.com to generate test data. If *that* goes through, odds are that all of your configuration is correct.